# how to allow the user to specify the names and the program will use that names for reporting results?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, increment, voting

this program is to tally the votes from total and each of four counties for two candidates.As well displaying the winner. The user has to input the votes for each county and the candidates. Now, thank to you guys, I worked out the kinks for the purpose stated above. But now, I want to add the Cout statements that will allow the user to specify the names of four counties and two candidates. as well using the names for reporting the result.

I am not sure how to incorporate the variables in the loop that will allow to print the names while reporting results like the overall winner, and the winner in each counties.

I appreciate your time!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int tier1();
int main(void)
{
 int return_val = tier1();
 if (return_val < 0) // print an error
 return 0;
}
int tier1(){
 int votes[8];
 int i, j, N; // variables
 int k = 0;
 for (i=0; i<4; i++)
 {
  cout << "county" << i << "\n"; // lists the 4 counties/candidates
  for (j=0; j<2; j++)
{
      cout << "How many votes did the candidate " << j << " get?\n";
      N=0;
       cin >> N;
      votes[k++] = N;;
   }
   if (votes[k-2] + votes[k-1] > 100) //checking if it goes over 100 votes
   {
    cout << "One of the counties has too many votes. Exiting!\n"; // Print an error
    exit(1);
   }

 }

 int candidateOneVotes = 0; //resetting 
 int candidateTwoVotes = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i+2)
 {
 cout << votes[i] << "\n";
 cout << votes[i+1] << "\n";
 candidateOneVotes += votes[i];
 candidateTwoVotes += votes[i+1];
 }
 if (candidateOneVotes > candidateTwoVotes){
 cout << "The winner of the election is " << c0 << "\n";
 }
 else
 {
 cout << "The winner of the election is " << c1 << "\n";
 }
 cout << "Here is the voting results:\n";
 cout << c0 << " got ";
 cout << candidateOneVotes;
 cout << " votes\n ";
 cout << c1 << "got ";
 cout << candidateTwoVotes;
 cout << " votes ";

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: You do realize this code won't compile, right?

Comment: Yes, It compiles and run without the cout statements in the top. I just added those cout statement as a idea, I know its incomplete and won't compile for now

Comment: If you want to see the program compile and run. I can remove the cout statements and int c0, c1,.... then it should run

Comment: I went ahead and edited out the part that I just added for an idea. basically, right now, the program should compile and run

Comment: In `main`, the comments lie.  You don't print an error message.  Instead, the `return` statement is tied to the `if` statement and becomes conditionally executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll want to pull in the contents of the string and vector headers.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

Next you'll want to update the declaration of `tier1` to accept two strings and a vector as aguments. This will allow you to pass the first and second candidate names along with a list of counties.

```
int tier1(
    const std::string& c0,
    const std::string& c1,
    const std::vector<std::string>& counties);
```

Now you'll want to update `main` to read the candidates and county names from `cin` and pass those names to the `tier1` function.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the VoteTime Program. Please do what it tells you.\n";

    std::string c0;
    cout << "Please name the candidate 0. (For example: Bob)\n";
    std::getline(cin, c0);

    std::string c1;
    cout << "Please name the candidate 1. (For example: John)\n";
    std::getline(cin, c1);

    std::vector<std::string> counties;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::string county;
        cout << "Please name county #" << i << '\n';
        std::getline(cin, county);
        counties.push_back(county);
    }


    int return_val = tier1(c0, c1, counties);

    if (return_val < 0) // print an error
        return 0;
}
```

Now you'll want to update the definition of `tier1` to accept two string arguments containing the candidate names and the vector containing the county names. Rather than relying on magic numbers to determine the number of counties you can call the `size` member function of the vector.

```
int tier1(
    const std::string& c0,
    const std::string& c1,
    const std::vector<std::string>& counties)
{
    int votes[8];
    int i, j, N; // variables
    int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < counties.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "county " << counties[i] << "\n";
        for (j = 0; j<2; j++)
        {
            cout << "How many votes did the candidate " << j << " get?\n";
            N = 0;
            cin >> N;
            votes[k++] = N;;
        }
        //checking if it goes over 100 votes
        if (votes[k - 2] + votes[k - 1] > 100)
        {
            cout << "One of the counties has too many votes. Exiting!\n";
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    int candidateOneVotes = 0; //resetting 
    int candidateTwoVotes = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 2)
    {
        cout << votes[i] << "\n";
        cout << votes[i + 1] << "\n";
        candidateOneVotes += votes[i];
        candidateTwoVotes += votes[i + 1];
    }
    if (candidateOneVotes > candidateTwoVotes){
        cout << "The winner of the election is " << c0 << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The winner of the election is " << c1 << "\n";
    }
    cout << "Here is the voting results:\n";
    cout << c0 << " got ";
    cout << candidateOneVotes;
    cout << " votes\n ";
    cout << c1 << "got ";
    cout << candidateTwoVotes;
    cout << " votes ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is definitely helpful! But I will need the user to specify the counties' name as well?

Comment: Updated answer to include support for counties. If you can't use `std::vector` switch to using naked arrays and smack your instructor.

Comment: I definitely appreciate your help. However, I got bunch of errors such as expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token, ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type, ‘vector’ is not a member of ‘std’, and ‘counties’ was not declared in this scope. in your original code, it worked perfectly, but after the support of counties, it gave me bunch of errors

Comment: You forgot `#include <vector>` :/

Comment: One thing I noticed that is after the user adds names for candidates. It asks 'how many votes did the candidate 0 get', instead of saying the name that user added? I am not sure how to approach this. in the end, it does say the name that user added. just not for when it asks. But for counties, it worked perfectly